# WCF Ria Services with identity Server

Tags: wpf, identityserver3, ria

I'm in a Silverlight migration project (with WCF Ria Services) to Open Ria Services (with WPF). Is there a way to get RIA domain services to work with identity server? Any samples?

Regards,

Andrés

Answer (score 0):

[this](https://leastprivilege.com/2015/07/02/give-your-wcf-security-architecture-a-makeover-with-identityserver3/) could be a good starting point (how to secure WCF services with JWT tokens)